# Calculating angular velocity of rolling object with just gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

From what I have learned, you can calculate what the angular velocity of an object will be based on its potential energy.

**Say there is a situation where:**

- acceleration due to gravity = 10 m/s²
- friction = infinite (object is in pure rolling motion)
- we know objects current state (velocity, angular velocity, etc..)
- slope angle = 13° above horizontal

**And I need to find:**

- objects angular velocity one second from current time

As you can see, I don't think I can use the potential energy conversion formula (maybe I can, but I am not seeing it).

Is there a way that I could find the 'future' angular velocity (in this case 1 second ahead) by just knowing the current 'state' of the object and that gravity will be affecting it?

**Edit:**

In my physics simulation, I find that given these values:

- gravity = g = 10 m/s²
- friction = μ = infinite
- radius of sphere = r = 0.5m
- angle of incline = θ = 13°

The angular acceleration is roughly 3 radians/s².

I just realized that if I could find the angular acceleration, I could then predict the angular velocity. Could someone help me find a formula to get the angular acceleration, with just knowing these values?

Comment: As you are considering both rotational and translational motion... I think one can use the energy conservation, off course in pure rolling. so change in P.E. can be equated to translational +rotational energy.

Comment: As regards finding  angular velocity - one can use  I.ang. accn. = torque , pl. look up<http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node108.html> for an intro.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of a solid sphere:
$I_{sphere}=\frac{2}{5}M{r_{sphere}^2}=0,4M{r_{sphere}}^2$

The torque applied:
$\tau=F_gsin(13)r_{sphere}=10M\times0,2r_{sphere}=0,2M r_{sphere}$

Just like $F=ma$, so $a=\frac{F}{m}$ in the linear case, we can write in the circular case:
$\alpha=\frac{\tau}{I}$, where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration. In this particular case, this becomes:

$\alpha=\frac{0,2M r_{sphere}}{0,4M{r_{sphere}}^2}=\frac{1}{2r_{sphere}}$ (unit $\frac{rad}{{sec}2}$).
Because $r_{sphere}=0,5$ we get

$\alpha=1\frac{rad}{{sec}^2}$

Now suppose the sphere rolls (initial velocities zero) for $10sec$ before arriving down the inclined plane. Obviously the sphere has an angular velocity (speed) of $\omega=10\frac{rad}{sec}$. The rotational energy of a body, in this case, a sphere, is
$E_{rot}=\frac{1}{2}I_{sphere}{\omega}^2$

We saw before the moment of inertia, in this case, is $0,4M{r_{sphere}}^2$ which for $r_{sphere}=0,5$ becomes $M$ (unit $\frac{kgm^2}{{sec}^2}$ or $Nm$). So the rotational energy is $5M$.

For evaluating the length of the plane ($l$) we have to compute $l=\frac{1}{2}\alpha t^2$ (like $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ in the linear motion case expressed im meters instead radians) so $l=50rad$. One radial corresponds to 57,3 degrees and because $r_{sphere}=0,5m$, $l=50\times57,3\times0,5=1432,5m$.

Now we can calculate the potential energy of the sphere on top of the plane. The height of the plane is $h=lsin(13)=1432,5\times0,2=286,5m$ The mass of the sphere is $M$. $E_{potsphere}=Mgh=2865M(J)$.

That's quite a difference with $5M(J)$! So almost ALL potential energy which the sphere has on the top is transformed in linear kinetic energy ($2860M(J)$) and only $5M(J)$ in rotational energy.

Answer (score -1):

**I found the angular acceleration using this formula:**

-5g/7r * sin θ

**where**

- g = acceleration due to gravity
- r = radius of sphere
- sin θ = angle of incline

Then used that to get velocity by multiplying it by time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course you can apply energy conservation or by simple work done by rotating force is given as
The mechanical work applied during rotation is the torque ($\tau$) times the rotation angle ($\theta$): 
$$W = \tau \theta$$

so that the work done is equal to $\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$.

Comment: I tried to improve grammar and formatting, but still don't fully understand what you mean to say. Please correct further to make it clear.

Comment: I simply apply work energy theorm work done by all forces.change in kinetic energy